# how to disable RTR logs in bluemix / cloud-foundry apps

Tags: logging, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

We have a simple REST API app deployed in bluemix.
Its serving a GET request like this `/api/users/v1/{sensitive-number}/info`
The problem is bluemix RTR logs as outlined here [cloud-foundry logs](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/streaming-logs.html)

always keep showing the full GET request path which in our case contains the {sensitive-number} value in plain, which we want either masked out or DISABLE the RTR logs completely.

For now we are looking for a way to completely DISABLE the RTR logs in this case, is that possible ?

I haven't found any documentation link that allows the user to do so.

Comment: I would avoid sending sensitive data in a GET url. Another route you can try is sending that sensitive data as form data with a POST request. You can read more here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29598/should-sensitive-data-ever-be-passed-in-the-query-string

Comment: I agree with you from security perspective, 

but then that goes against the RESTful way of doing things, from my research online, i figure we really are 'GET'ing the resources in this case not 'POST'ing to them.

Is there anything we can do to avoid showing the full urls in the logs (still disabling the RTR logs is a preferred option for us - if possible)

Comment: Is your "sensitive-number" really sensitive then? For example, if it's just a UUID that is mapped to a profile or something similar does it really need to be hidden? 

If the data returned from this call is sensitive then I would also suggest having the user pass through an Authentication token with their requests so you know who is asking for this information. Also sorry, I do not know how to disable the RTR logs, I am just seeing if these other alternatives can help as well.

Comment: yes the 'sensitive-number' is sensitive information, its not a UUID. 
The reason i mentioned it should be GET request (instead of POST) is because we are actually pulling information regarding the sensitive-number from the backend.

So the question as to how to disable the RTR logs in bluemix still stands. thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Bluemix public regions, the RTR logs cannot be disabled because they would be disabled for every customer using that region. Some other customers using that region might rely on those logs. However, if you are a dedicated or local customer, there is a possibility that it can be changed in your environment. This change in a dedicated or local environment would require a Bluemix Support Ticket: https://ibm.biz/support_widget_instructions

Comment: @Bill Wentworth Can we disable RTR logs in pivotal cloud foundry?

Comment: @Dhamvir Tiwari - I am not familiar with the Pivotal environment.